# How to remove last repetitive word from text file in terminal

Tags: terminal

i have a txt file and want remove last tcp from that txt file .

```
$cat textfile
 886/tcp
 885/tcp
 884/tcp
```

i want textfile like Below

```
$cat textfile
 886
 885
 884
```

i don't have idea how resolve on terminal and thank you for your efforts

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what you have tried so far to solve your problem, so we have a basis to work with you toward your solution. Also please specify if you are a Windows/Max/Linux user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the cut command:

```
cat textFile | cut -d '/' -f 1
```

Output:

```
886
885
884
```

Command flags explanation:

- -d: lets you specify the delimiter to split on. In this case "/"
- -f: lets you choose which substring of the split to choose. In this case we want the first substring so: 1

Comment: Does this answer your question @sonu Agarwal?